# Locally Finite Groups and Quotients

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $M = \cap N$ such that $N \unlhd G$ and $G/N$ is locally finite. Then $G/M$ is locally finite group?

Comment: Please explain your notation for $M$.

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you. For example, are you convinced that $\cap N$ is normal? (Also, @user37238, I presume the set up is that we have a class of normal subgroups $N$ and we are wanting to show properties of $\widehat{N}=\cap N$, namely, that $G/\widehat{N}$ is locally finite.)

Comment: @user1729 is Obviously that $\cap N$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: @user37238 My notation for $M$ is:
$M = \displaystyle \bigcap_{N \unlhd G} N$ such that $G/N$ is a locally finite group.

Comment: I tried to take a finite subset in $G/M$ and prove that the subgroup generated by this set was finite. However unable to use the hypothesis that $G/N$ is locally finite. So I do not know if this subgroup is in fact or not.

Comment: @user1729 This problem is not my homework. I'm trying to solve a problem and would like to reduce to the case where the group is locally finite.

Comment: @Eidu I think you want to use the fact that all homomorphic images of $G/M$ are locally finite (I think this used choice though). Then the "infinite bit" of $\langle S\rangle$ must disappear into the kernel of all the homomorphic images, and so into the trivial group. Does that make sense?

Comment: The statement is false in an infinite cyclic group. Is it possible that there is confusion between locally finite and residually finite?

Comment: @DerekHolt is false? I'll think about your example. Anyway, thank you very much.